# Как спросить права администратора?

Tags: windows, x86, x86-64, c++, qt

Приложения должно быть запущено с правами администратора. Как спросить пользователя это?
Как проверить, что он согласился? Как узнать, запущено ли уже приложения от имени администратора, чтобы не спрашивать, или это не нужно?

Сделал так, как описано [здесь](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27264) пользователем ChrisW67.
Результата не получил.
Если можно, то дайте пример "хеллов вордовского" проекта.

P.S в примере и у меня архитектура 86. На 64 нужно что-то менять? Операционная система Windows 7. Пишу в Qt Creator. Qt5

Comment: @tioo, ну уж в таком-то специфическом вопросе **ОС** надо бы указать.

Comment: @avp у меня windows 7. На linux также интересно.

Comment: В винде не знаю.

--


А в linux...

Проще всего заранее присвоить (рутом) загрузочному модулю owner : root и выставить `s` бит. 

Простая программка a.out просто делает файл "xaxa"


    avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ ./a.out 
    uid: 1000 euid: 1000
    avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ ll xaxa
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 avp avp 0 May  8 20:01 xaxa
    avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ sudo chown root a.out
    avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ sudo chmod +s a.out
    avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ ./a.out 
    uid: 1000 euid: 0
    avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ ll xaxa
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 root avp 0 May  8 20:02 xaxa
    avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ 
    
Видите?

Comment: @avp, да, спасибо. теперь винда.

Comment: Если по какой-то причине это недоступно, то придется запускать через sudo (читайте man, особенно обратите внимание на настройки привилегий  в /etc/sudo.conf. Естественно их можно менять только рутом).

Если это не проходит (ну, никак Вам рут не хочет помочь), то посмотрите на `ssh` (только ее придется запускать через pty, чтобы рутовый пароль скормить. Для упрощения программирования см. `man forkpty`) или `su`.

Однако, и они для рута могут быть закрыты. 

Тогда... Конкретную конфигурацию надо смотреть (это как руткит какой-нибудь в систему подсунуть).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вас интересует относится к подсистеме *UAC* и называется повышением прав (*elevation*). Собственно, предлагаю поискать по этим двум ключевым словам.

Так же на MSDN есть готовый [пример работы с UAC-ом на С++](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppUACSelfElevation-5bfc52dd). Рекомендую взглянуть.

Comment: @tioo: Кстати, уже запущенная программа [не может](http://superuser.com/a/129038/56347) повысить свои права. Вы должны либо запустить другую копию программы (как это показано в примере), либо требовать права через manifest (и тогда они будут доступны при самом запуске). Других методов под Windows нет.