# Как повысить привилегии приложения (UAC)

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi

Делаю приложение, которое запускается на Windows 7/10 от пользователя с правами администратора. При этом запускается оно в обычном режиме (с ограниченными правами). Приложению этих прав хватает на всё, кроме одной редко используемой операции.
 Вопрос: можно ли как-то во время исполнения приложения запросить повышение привилегий для его процесса **без перезапуска (создания нового) процесса**? 
Т.е. как в некоторых стандартных диалогах Windows есть функции, помеченные значком щита, при вызове которых появляется стандартный запрос UAC на повышение прав доступа.

Comment: ищите по словам Windows Privilege Escalation

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/318691/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0/318807#318807

Comment: Без перезапуска http://superuser.com/questions/129034/elevate-a-running-program-to-administrator-windows-7/129038#129038 кажись не может.

Comment: @nick_n_a FAR, MPC-HE и некоторые приложения от майкрософта делают. Видимо, всё-таки можно

Comment: Total Commander точно создаёт новый процесс. Похоже, что действительно невозможно, спасибо.

Comment: @nick_n_a Так у FAR'а исходники лежат, IDA не нужен вроде как... Или с ним быстрее? :)

Comment: Вроде как elevation.cpp и elevation.hpp https://github.com/FarGroup/FarManager/tree/master/far  Но я не настолько силён в c++, чтобы полностью разобраться сам.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov фар создаёт новый процесс с повышеными привелегиями и через него делает доступ.

Comment: @nick_n_a Ясно... Жаль, значит, магии не существует :)

Answer (score 1):

Без создания нового процесса - нельзя, без перезапуска - можно.

Алгоритм действия такой (для того, что бы не делать перезапуск):

1. Cоздаём процесс с повышенными привелегиями, можно вызвать свой же модуль, но с параметром, по-которому наша программа "переключится" на запасной режим работы, например через runas (читать UAC).
2. Ждём отклика от процесса (пока пользователь в диалоге UAC разрешит)
3. Передаем новому процессу параметры для вызова одной АПИ (DuplicateHandle, WriteProcessMemory, CreatePipe, Write и т п)
4. Передаём процессу сигнал запустить функцию
5. Ждём ответа процесса (пока ф-ция отработает) ( с помощью WaitForSingleObject например).
6. Считываем ответ (ReadProcessMemory, Read)
7. Замораживаем нить процесса, что бы повторно использовать.
8. По завершению работы программы так же завершаем процесс с админскими привелегиями (или через TerminateProcess, или передаём сигнал процессу).

При этом визуально не будет понятно, что основной процесс создал дополнительный.